# Passing a value from a button in javascript to a function that creates a localStorage variable

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a survey web app at work to collect data from customers.  I'm trying to convert a dozen different functions (one for each option) into one simple function.  The "votes" are stored as localStorage variables so that the survey can be reopened each day without losing data.  Here is what I have:

```
<script>

function vote(choice)
{
   if (localStorage.choice)
   {
      localStorage.choice=Number(localStorage.choice)+1;
   }
   else
   {
      localStorage.choice=1;
   }
   alert("Thanks for your input!  Have a nice day");
}

</script>
```

And then I have buttons in the body that look like this:

```
<li class="li" onClick="vote(a);">choice 1</li>
<li class="li" onClick="vote(b);">choice 2</li>
<li class="li" onClick="vote(c);">choice 3</li>
```

Functions work just fine if I have separate ones for each, what am I doing wrong to pass the letters into new localStorage variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use properties of an object dynamically you have to use `[]` notation

```
<script>

function vote(choice)
{
   if (localStorage[choice])
   {
      localStorage[choice]=Number(localStorage[choice])+1;
   }
   else
   {
      localStorage[choice]=1;
   }
   alert("Thanks for your input!  Have a nice day");
}

</script>
```

To pass the letters as strings you have to quote them

```
<li class="li" onClick="vote('a');">choice 1</li>
<li class="li" onClick="vote('b');">choice 2</li>
<li class="li" onClick="vote('c');">choice 3</li>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u49vK/)

Comment: You forgot the brackets for choice in Number argument.

Comment: @MikeW You can only use dot notation if you know the propery at the time the code is written, this is not the case as the op passes the properties to the function.

Comment: Why the -1 on this answer? Looks fine to me. Also, `localStorage.choice` will not work here. Picture refactoring the function argument to `chosen`. It should now be obvious why `choice` would no longer apply to the dynamic `chosen`.

Answer (score 2):

`a`, `b`, and `c` are variables. You should use string literals:

```
<li class="li" onClick="vote('a');">choice 1</li>
<li class="li" onClick="vote('b');">choice 2</li>
<li class="li" onClick="vote('c');">choice 3</li>
```

Comment: this is only a part of the answer, and you are assuming that `a`,`b`,`c` isn't global variables. Also what you did is making strings containing `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`